# mongoexport, projection in query

Tags: mongoexport

On MongoDb.exe I can do a query with projection only ONE a field like this:

> db.cache_sta.find({ip:"10.5.8.17"},{_id:0, hostname:1})
>       { "hostname" : "iPad-Blanka" }

I try do the same but by mongoexport.exe

```
mongoexport.exe /h 127.0.0.1:27117 /d ace /c cache_sta /q {ip:\"10.5.8.17\"},{"_id":0,hostname:1}
```

results:

```
error validating settings: query '{ip:"10.5.8.17"},{_id:0,hostname:1}' is not valid JSON: invalid character ',' after top-level value
```

Comment: I try alternative way but it's not work: `mongo.exe -port 27117 ace --eval "db.cache_sta.find({ip:\"10.5.2.59\"},{_id:0,hostname:1});"` results:
`MongoDB shell version: 3.0.4
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27117/ace
DBQuery: ace.cache_sta -> { "ip" : "10.5.2.59" }`

Answer (score 1):

Solution to display only hostname field for document with specific ip field is:

```
mongo -port 27117 -host 127.0.0.1 ace --quiet --eval "db.cache_sta.find({ip:'10.5.2.84'}, {_id:0,hostname:1}).forEach(printjson)"
```

Output:

```
{ "hostname" : "GWF090L" }
```